# Commiting new changes to Gunicorn + Nginx + Django dockerized application in server

Tags: python, django, docker, deployment

Docker novice here.

I have committed new changes inside the application. These changes where copied from my local to host machine, and then to docker container.
So I created a new image `sudo docker commit old_container_id new_image_name(djangotango-on-docker_web)`

Then I spin the docker container by using new image created.

sudo docker  run --name djangotango-web -d --expose 8000 djangotango-on-docker_web gunicorn djangotango.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000

Here `djangotango-on-docker_web` is my new image created.

But my application gives 502 error after this. My new container is not synced properly.

`dockerfile`

```
version: '3.8'

# networks: 
#   public_network:
#     name: public_network
#     driver: bridge

services:
  web:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    # image: <aws-account-id>.dkr.ecr.<aws-region>.amazonaws.com/django-ec2:web
    command: gunicorn djangotango.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      # - .:/home/app/web/
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/static
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/media    
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.staging
    networks: 
      service_network:
 
  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.staging.db
    networks: 
      service_network:
    # depends_on: 
    #   - web
  
  # pgadmin:
  #   image: dpage/pgadmin4
  #   env_file: 
  #     - ./.env.staging.db
  #   ports:
  #     - "8080:80"
  #   volumes:
  #     - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
  #   depends_on: 
  #     - db
  #   links: 
  #     - "db:pgsql-server"
  #   environment: 
  #     - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=4652173624824872
  #     - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=exampleeee
  #     - PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=80
  #   networks: 
  #     service_network:

  nginx-proxy:
    build: nginx
    # image: <aws-account-id>.dkr.ecr.<aws-region>.amazonaws.com/django-ec2:nginx-proxy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 443:443  
      - 80:80
    networks: 
      service_network:
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/static
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/media 
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    labels:
      - "com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy"
    depends_on:
      - web

  nginx-proxy-letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    env_file:
      - .env.staging.proxy-companion
    networks: 
      service_network:
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy
  
networks: 
  service_network:
   
volumes:
  postgres_data:
  pgadmin-data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
  certs:
  html:
  vhost:
```

How to do it in correct way? I'm running my production application on my domain name.
What I can understand from logs is, my web is not in same network as other container now.
I don't want to rebuild my docker-compose which will solve the problem but will increase the image size, plus it's not recommended I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct approach here is to use only `docker-compose` commands, and to go ahead and rebuild your image:

```
docker-compose up --build --force-recreate web
```

Many of the options you'd need to recreate this with a plain `docker run` command are listed in the `docker-compose.yml` file, but some generated implicitly.  The `docker run` command you show doesn't have a `--net` option to attach to the Compose network (which could result in the error you're getting), and it doesn't have the `-v` options to overwrite the image's static files with content from a volume or the settings from the `.env.staging` file.

You should almost never use `docker commit` either.  What's the code change you made in your image, and how would your colleagues get and test that change?  Especially with the mentions of "prod" here, running code in production that you haven't built from source and tested through your usual CI process is usually discouraged.

(In terms of image size, a committed image will always be larger than the original image; `docker build` a new image will start from the base image and generally be smaller.  Committing images also tends to lose options like the default command to run.)